# Is Mongolian "шинэ" / "ᠰᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ", meaning "new", a borrowing of Chinese "新"?

Tags: etymology, borrowing, chinese, mongolian

I've noticed that the Mongolian word for "new" is "шинэ" (or in traditional script, "ᠰᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ"). Since final vowels are not pronouned it's spoken as "shin".

The Han character for "new", "新" is also pronounced pretty much as "shin" in Mandarin, Korean, and Japanese.

Is the Mongolian word also derived from Chinese? It seems like it ought to be core vocabulary but as its been borrowed into Korean and Japanese it seems quite possible though those other languages facilitated a greater degree of borrowing due to using the Chinese writing system.

Comment: I see in (Russian) Buryat *new* is "шэнэ" and Kalmyk it is "шин", so it does seem to be part of Mongolic core vocabulary which makes me lean more toward coincidence.

Comment: Mongolia is not ᠮᠣᠨᠭᠭᠣᠯ, It should be like ᠮᠣᠩᠭᠣᠯ in traditional Mongolian.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible for Khalkha Mongolian шинэ *šine* to be related in some way to Chinese 新 *xīn* “new”, but it is hard to say for sure. The term might be a borrowing the Middle Chinese (c. from 4th to 9th century): notice that the reconstructed pronunciation of 新 *xīn* is *sin* in Middle Chinese.

As Janus Bahs Jacquet has pointed out, this Chinese word can be connected to PTB **siŋ* ~ **sik* “tree, wood” ([STEDT #2658](https://stedt.berkeley.edu/%7Estedt-cgi/rootcanal.pl/etymon/2658)), an equivalence also recognized by Schuessler (2007: 538). However, the Mongolian form can only come from Middle Chinese, in light of the pronunciation of the final alveolar nasal. As you have noticed yourself, there are cognates in other Mongolic languages, such as Buryat шэнэ *šene*, Kalmyk шин *šin*, but also Eastern Yugur *šənə*, Mongghul *śinə*, Mangghuer *ʂïni*, Kangjia *šini*, Dongxiang *ʂïni*, etc. To these, we could also add Kalmyk *senr* and Written Mongolian *sener* “new, fresh” (Ramstedt 1935: 324). According to Nugteren (2011: 496-97), the reconstruction of this word in Proto-Mongolic could be **šini* or **šine*. The former (with final **i*) seems suggested by the languages of the Qinghai-Gansu region, while the latter (with final **e*) appears to be more common in Central Mongolic. Apart from this, we find the same doublet in Middle Mongolian, which has شيني *šyny* (= *šini*), شينه *šynh* (= *šine*) in the *Muqaddimat al-Adab* (Muq 9v, 360r), *šini* in the *Secret History of the Mongols* (SH 265, 1r), and 失你 *šini* in the *Hua-Yi yiyu* (see [HY](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hans/%E8%8F%AF%E5%A4%B7%E8%AD%AF%E8%AA%9E)). Finally, Written Mongolian has both *sine* and *sini* as well (Lessing 1960: 711, 713). Because the variant with **i* is widely spread, we cannot conclude if the proto-form ended in **i* or in **e*.

Khitan <ś.ên> “new” (Kane 2009: 38) is rather divergent from the phonetic point of view, but I don’t think anyone would object to its inclusion in the family of words. It is true that such form lacks the final vowel, however this kind of phonetic erosion at the end of the word appears to be common in Khitan, cf. e.g. <g.úr> “state, country” (Kane 2009: 89), which corresponds to Khalkha Mongolian гүрэн *güren* “country” (< **güren*), and is also very similar to Jurchen *gurun* and Manchu *gurun* “country”, or <ci.is> “blood relation” (Kane 2009: 39), akin to Written Mongolian *čisu* “blood” (< **cïsu/n*). So, at least in theory, the possibility that a lemma such as Khitan <ś.ên> is related to Mongolic **sine* or **sini* should not be ruled out. Whether or not there was a final vowel in this word, once we go back to the most ancient stages of the development of Khitan, cannot be demonstrated conclusively, but this fact does not make the contribution we get from this language less interesting or valuable. Khitan was a Para-Mongolic language (see Janhunen 2003, 2012, 2023) spoken since at least (but most likely even before) the 10th century, so it is attested earlier than Middle Mongolian (fl. 13th century) in terms of written records.

In conclusion, taking into account the data from Medieval and Modern Mongolic languages together with Khitan, we can assume that, if Proto-Mongolic **sine/i* was borrowed from Chinese 新 *xīn*, then it must have happened very early in the pre-history of Mongolic languages, possibly during the Pre-Proto-Mongolic period. On one hand, there are no glaring obstacles to this hypothesis from the point of view of the phonology and the semantics, while, on the other, historical written sources are per se unable to confirm or reject it. Is it possible that Mongolian шинэ *šine* “new” is related to Chinese 新 *xīn* “new”? Yes, absolutely. Is it plausible? Yes, it is! But we cannot prove it.

### Primary sources

Muq = *Muqaddimat al-Adab* (c. XII-XIV century AD)
SH = *Secret History of the Mongols* (c. 1227 AD)
YH = 华夷译语 *Huá-Yí yìyǔ* (1382 AD)

### References

- Janhunen, Juha A. 2003. Para-Mongolic. In Janhunen, Juha A. (Ed.) *The Mongolic Languages*, 391-402. London: Routledge.
- Janhunen, Juha A. 2012. Khitan: Understanding the Language Behind the Scripts. *Scripta* 4: 107-132.
- Janhunen, Juha A. 2023. The Unity and Diversity of Altaic. *Annual Review of Linguistics* 9: 135-154.
- Kane, Daniel. 2009. *The Khitan Language and Script*. Leiden & Boston: Brill.
- Lessing, Ferdinand D. 1960. *Mongolian-English Dictionary*. Berkeley & Los Angeles: University of California Press.
- Nugteren, Hans. 2011. *Mongolic Phonology and the Qinghai-Gansu Languages*. Utrecht: LOT.
- Ramstedt, Gustaf J. 1935. *Kalmückisches Wörterbuch*. Helsinki: Suomalais-Ugrilainen Seura.
- Schuessler, Axel. 2007. *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*. Honolulu: University of Hawai’i Press.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, the Chinese phoneme is not exactly sh but it sounds more like **k** in Swedish *käften*.

Contrary to the information provided by YS, *more exact* spelling of the other language is [Khitan](http://ikipedia.org/wiki/Khitan_language) (with H) or Liao and its relation to Mongolian is at least disputable.

The Khitan word does not prove anything, because this is a distant language of a disputed and not widely recognised branch, *but these are the minor inaccuracies.*

What really matters is that the final vowel used to be pronounced in older Mongolian only, but not in Khitan (which is clear even from the poor and insufficient evidence provided by YS).

And it is far more important that the proto Sino-Tibetan word for 'new' has been reconstructed as ¤saR; that is, as a monosyllablic word with a final consonant R [(see Paul K. Benedict, p. 163).](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521118077)

Comment: To begin with, there's no agreement on whether there is one Chinese phoneme, or two allophones of a single phoneme. `[ʂ]` and `[ɕ]` are in complementary distribution so various analyses either group or split them. And I'm sure it/they has/have changed since the time the various languages borrowed it anyway, which is why I didn't go off on that tangent d-;

Comment: And I have no idea why you're talking about Khitan. I didn't mention this at all... Ah you should mention YS's answer if you reference it. There's no guarantee of the order answers will be presented or read in.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the [ʂ] and [ɕ], but they are rendered as *s- in most of reconstructions. The rest is more about YS's answers.

Comment: I have to admit to not being very good at Proto-Sinitic, Proto-Sino-Tibetan, or protolanguage reconstructions at all actually. I find etymological dictionaries frustratingly difficult to use. If we had a blog we could have an article on that topic! (=

Comment: Your argument does not rule out the possibility that Mongolic borrowed a monosyllabic term from an early Chinese and added a final epenthetic "e" for phonotactic reasons. Indeed in my embryonic studies of traditional Mongolian script there are many final silent "e"s among other epenthetic sounds and silent letters. **Oops** looks like I missed the point of which final consonant there was ...

Comment: There is no suffucient data on whether Khitan was an Altaic (Mongolian) language or not, and I think we have not enought information about the common borrowing patterns, either.

Comment: ...and other historical forms are *sienz or *sieny, but, again, I am not sure about the timelines of these two (proto)languages (the *ser is definately proto Sino-Tibetan, but I am not sure about its cognates *sieny and *sienz).

Comment: Could you provide a quote from the Benedict source for the PST root _*saR-_? I don’t go into PST much, but I was under the impression that the standard view is that adopted by Wiktionary, namely that 新 derives from [PST _*siŋ ~ *sik_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Sino-Tibetan/siŋ_~_sik) with a final nasal (or velar, but not in the relevant Chinese forms where the Mongolian word may have been borrowed from). Certainly I’ve never seen an OC reconstruction for this word that didn’t have a final nasal, and anything beyond OC is likely not relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

This word can well be connected with its Chinese counterpart. The Old Mongolian for it is `sine`, the Kitan (Super Old Mongolian) is `*shen`.

Comment: It seems that Classical Mongolian did not (at least usually) have final consonants. Often in the Cyrillic spelling the final vowels are not written, but when they are they are not pronounced. In the traditional script spellings there are a lot more written final vowels which are silent but. The traditional script preserves the Classical Mongolian whereas the Cyrillic is more "reformed". Not that any of that directly affects this word but it's interesting to know.

Comment: Even the Classical Mongolian word `monggol` has a final consonant, and there are tons of other words with a final consonant, here are some of them, the ones that I could remember first: `han` (khan), `hoyar` (2), `arban` (10), `bičig` (script, writing), `on` (year), etc. And I have something special for you, it's my scan of a 1989 Mongolian book that teaches how to write Mongolian in the traditional Mongolian script, for those who are used to writing in Cyrillic. Just tell me where it's better for you that I post the link to download it.

Comment: Yes sorry I'm far too new at Mongolian to have commented on this stuff. I don't know the current phonotactics or what has changed over the centuries in the phonotactics since Classical Mongolian. I just know that there are various quirks. *Монгол* = ᠮᠣᠨᠭᠭᠣᠯ has a final consonant in both traditional and Cyrillic, but *хэл* has a final consonant in Cyrillic but ended with a vowel (e) in traditional ᠬᠡᠯᠡ.